# Get the number of hours as Integer instead of string

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to echo only the integer from this script.

```php
<?php
$hour = '<script type="text/javascript">
var x = new Date().getHours();
document.write(x)
</script>';

var_dump($hour);
```

my output from this is

```
string(93) "17"
```

but I just want to get my output as `17` as an integer.

When I try using `parseInt` it outputs `0`.

How can I  get it to output `17` instead of `0`?

Comment: `var_dump((int)$hour);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver, I already tried that, it still sent out ```0```

Comment: Why not use `\DateTime()`? Example: `$date = new \DateTime(); var_dump($date->format('H'));`

Comment: `string(93) "17"` there is more to this than meet the eye! 93 chars means you are vardumping the whole string from `<script` to `</script>`, the js is not being executed

Comment: Ha @RiggsFolly yes I read too fast and missed that.

Comment: @AbraCadaver No need to apologise to me my friend

Comment: So you can't just assign JS to a string and have it execute and store the result in that string. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: You need to learn about the [difference between client and server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming). Also, there is no need to use JS here. The current hour can be fetched with PHP.

Comment: @hppycoder, I want to get the user time in real-time and not make use of server time

Comment: If you want time from the client, then you will need to employ AJAX to pass that value to PHP.

Comment: Then you have to write a page in HTML with some JS in it, then send the date back to the PHP using AJAX

Comment: Then PHP needs to be told what the browser time is. Passed through an AJAX call or some other way like a form. The server will only ever know what the server time is. It cannot possibly know what the browser is because that's on the client side

Comment: @El_Vanja, I want to get the user time in real-time and not make use of server time

Comment: _I think we are all singing of the same Hymn sheet here_ :) :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Isn't that the point of a choir, though? :)

Comment: I bet we would all be good friends in real life

Comment: Wouldnt want to meet @El_Vanja in a dark alley judging by his picture :) :)

Comment: Okay guys, let me try this. Thanks for the melody. I hope it puts my code to sleep. :)

Comment: You got this @UbyjudeJosh. This is a good concept to learn because it affects more than just PHP and will set you up for nearly all other future endeavors as well

Comment: I would love to know how you managed to claim that var_dump produced `string(93) "17"` thats a bit of magic

Comment: Thanks, @hppycoder!

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I used an online debugger to run my PHP code when it stopped displaying on local

Comment: Try VCCode and XDEBUG, work like a dream